# how to remove empty characters in php?

Tags: php

How to remove empty characters no space from html content? The variable $str have some spaces and some no spaces. The following code can't remove all the empty characters. I try to use trim function it also can't been removed.

```
$str='<div>    test test test   test</div>';
$html='/\s*/';
$newstr=preg_replace($html,'',$str);
echo $newstr;
```

My expected result:

```
<div>testtesttesttest</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me! What is your current output and what do you expect?

Comment: did u tried : trim()

Comment: can you post your expected result?

Comment: @Vincent Wong show your expected answer

Comment: this link work for me. http://alvinalexander.com/php/php-string-strip-characters-whitespace-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try php [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
$str='<div>    test test test   test</div>';
$newstr=trim($str);
echo $newstr;  //output: test test test test
```

Alertnatively:

```
$str='<div>    test test test   test</div>';
$newstr = str_replace(' ','',$str);
echo $newstr; //output : testtesttesttest
```

Comment: @Vincent Wong let me know,if it is working for you :)

Comment: what does `$html='/\s*/';` here?

Comment: @Priyank Wrong output is: `string(36) "<div>    test test test   test</div>"` <- Multiple spaces as before

Comment: @RakeshSharma sorry i forgot to remove.thanks see my update answer :)

Comment: trim can't remove spaces from middle? it's only for remove spaces from start and end of string

Comment: @Vincent Wong try any of this: see my updated answer.

Comment: try like this 
$str = '<div>    test test test   test</div>';
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);

Comment: the empty characters and spaces been displayed are different from dreamweaver program. empty characters been displayed empty circle, spaces been displayed solid circle.